# "Such requests" versus "those requests"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *such requests*, and *these/those requests*?

For example, consider these sentences that are taken from a sentence making a list of requests:

> Such requests cannot be accepted.

> These requests cannot be accepted.

What is the difference between the first and the second sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My interpretation of the difference is that "Such requests cannot be accepted" means "requests *such as* these", in other words the list of requests given is a representative sample of the sort of request that cannot be accepted.

"These requests cannot be accepted," on the other hand, means that these *specific* requests are, for some reason, unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

*Such requests* means *requests of this type*. *These requests* refers to a specific set of requests.